# In what order does .find() return MongoDB documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, document, text-classification

I was wondering if there is a certain "order" of some sort in which MongoDB documents are returned when querying like this:

```
collection.find()
```

Is it always the same, given that *collection* does not change? Does MongoDB have some kind of order? There is an empty query, so it will just retrieve any document.
I'm asking because this is for classification. I want to retrieve a bunch of documents to train a model on. The test set cannot include documents from that same set, so I do this:

```
trainset = collection.find().limit(train_set_size)
testset = collection.find().skip(train_set_size).limit(test_set_size)
```

So both sets will have absolutely no overlap.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `collection.find()` return based on `id`. In `mongodb` `ObjectId` is based on time.So it should be `LIFO`(Last in First Out).So sorting is based on `time`.

In your set, there should be no overlap

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify an specific order, you can't rely on the order of the returned results. In general the results are returned in the order they are found, which may coincide with insertion order or the order of the index(es) used.